# Переменная bool зависимая от значения float

Tags: c#

Нужно заиметь 2 переменные: флоат и бул.

И что бы при изменении Float, этот Bool был завязан на значения Float.

Выше некоторого уровня - true; 
Ниже некоторого уровня - false.

Этот "некий уровень" должен задаватся в отдельной переменной.

Не знаю как написать это правильно кодом.

Comment: Никак, вот это `float bool = true` просто не скомпилируется, так как float - это число, а не bool

Comment: @tym32167 Я имею ввиду, в духе: 
if(float *увеличивается*)
{
bool = true;
}else if{
bool = false;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ужасающе плохо напианый вопрос. Но, думаю, я вопрос понял.

Должно быть как-то так:

```
float _floatZeroVal = 1.0f;

public float FloatVal = 1.0f;

public bool FloatIsLargerThanZero {
    get
    {
        return FloatVal > _floatZeroVal;
    }
}
```

в таком случае `FloatVal` и `FloatIsLargerThanZero` те переменные которые ты хотел.

Comment: Только начинаю осваивать программирование, да, это именно то, что нужно)

Comment: я проапдейтил вопрос к более ясной формулировке. Для будущих поколений. Если там что-то не так написал - подправь.